# Please set the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE enviroment variable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, activepython

I'm using windows 10 with python 2.7.10 with activepython in GAE

im getting this error after trying to run a script with a library that i just installed called pycrypto:

```
"Please set the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE enviroment variable"

RuntimeError: Please set the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE enviroment variable
```

how can i find this python-eggs folder in windows to set the proper environment variable?

Thanks

Comment: That error, including `enviroment` typo is from an older version of setuptools. Try to upgrade setuptools and reinstall pycrypto and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just did an upgrade but i still get the same errors

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Have you solved this? I have exactly the same issue with the same library in the same conditions

Comment: hello, i couldnt solve it, what i did was that i removed everything and installed python 2.7 again, also checkout for your app.yaml file because if you are using a package that is not supported by your version of python 2.7.* but it is written in your app.yaml it may cause more probems

Answer (score 0):

All

I've the same error for installed package MySQL-python version 1.2.5,
if downgrade the package to version 1.2.3, it's work fine.

I hope that it will be helpful for you:
link to distribution package http://www.codegood.com/archives/129

=====
also the error will appear when some dependent packages wasn't installed  successfully.